# In App Purchase Validation and Verification Server for PHP

Tags: php, android, ios, in-app-purchase

Is there any open source and universal tool for PHP to validate and verify IN APP Purchase for Android and iOS?

I want to store all information in local database and keep full history.
My applications have to send initial receipt and call an API to verify timeliness of this receipt.

Comment: Do you mean you want to communicate between you ios,android app and php code.?

Comment: Exactly. I want to communicate in two directions.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you have to make webservices in php...which return data to you app in xml or json format. which is readable for your app. you app will send data to that services in xml or json format so you php code will get it and process. For this purpose you must have knowledge about webservices and

Comment: I know.. :) I've made a couple Web Services in PHP and REST API connections. I want to only know that is it any Open Source and ready to use implementation in PHP for my needs.

Comment: thats fine. :) Please eleborate your question? I did'nt understand.?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS applications you can try to use [In-App Purchase Server](http://in-app-purchase-server.com/). This is not a open source project, but it has Free service plan (and will have it always).

Service will support Android applications in the future too, but I can't say exactly when it will appear.

If you have any questions about this service we can discuss its here or by e-mail: support@in-app-purchase-server.com

Comment: Thanks maxd. I want to build local solution for my company. It has to be on our servers :)